# Verifying my email address for AppleID: Where is the verification link?

Tags: icloud

When setting up my AppleID I get a verification email but there doesn't seem to be a link to click on. There is a line that says "Verify now" but it's not a link. The only other thing on the page is a link to Apple that starts the process all over again.

Does anyone have a solution for this problem?

Comment: If the automated system sends you two incorrectly formatted verification links, something is amiss with your account and you'll need to make a new one or contact a human at the iTunes billing support web site. You will be able to enter an alternate email and phone number for a person with access to the systems to diagnose and assist you.

Answer (score 4):

I got this fixed. I went to [appleid.apple.com](http://appleid.apple.com/), clicked on "Manage your account", logged in, and then clicked on "Send verification email"; the email had a link in it.

Comment: As 2019 this is no longer true. appleid.apple.com works but it does not provide any "send verification email" any more.

Answer (score 2):

Check the source of the page in your email. Look for a line after "...using your Apple ID and password." There should be a link, something along the lines of:

some code - "https://id.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/IDMSAccount.woa/wa/vetemail?language=...followed by about 2 lines of random letters" - more code.

Copy whatever is between " " and paste it in a new tab. It should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

In the body of the verification email that Apple sends to you, there should be a link after the first paragraph (which should have your new email address) with the text:

> Verify Now >

Click on that link and you'll be able to verify your account.

Answer (score 0):

Since your Apple ID can be used for purchasing, Apple will support you in the basics of maintaining it - making changes to email, etc...

http://www.apple.com/support/appleid/

If you can't use the articles to narrow down your issue - just keep on the site - asking for billing support and say you'd like to make sure this Apple ID is set up to purchase from the App Store / iTunes store and you will eventually get a person or a form to email and leave your contact information / phone number + email if the Apple employee can't resolve the issue without speaking with you.